# How do I recover data from an encrypted Home directory

Tags: encryption

I opted to encrypt my Home during install, and now I would like to access my data from a LiveCD, unfortunately I'm having trouble following these [instructions](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10050388). I get the error "mounting eCryptfs: [-2] No such file or directory"

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you can use the `ecryptfs-recover-private` tool now included in Ubuntu 11.04:

[Recover your Encrypted Private Directory](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html)

Comment: Sometimes this gives `Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]` even though the passphrase is correct. As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285541/mount-no-such-file-or-directory-with-encrypted-recovery/395391#comment878481_395391, it's helpful to run `sudo ecryptfs-manager`, then press 4 (exit), then run `ecryptfs-recover-private` again.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you recover data from an encrypted home: (sdx should be your SATA drive)

```
sudo mkdir /recovery
sudo mount /dev/sdx /recovery
sudo mount -o bind /dev /recovery/dev
sudo mount -o bind /dev/shm /recovery/dev/shm
sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /recovery/dev/pts
sudo mount -o bind /sys /recovery/sys
sudo mount -o bind /proc /recovery/proc
sudo mv /recovery/etc/resolv.conf /recover/etc/resolv.conf.orig
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /recovery/etc/resolv.conf

sudo mkdir /data-recovery
sudo mkdir /recovery/data-recovery
sudo mount --rbind /data-recovery /recovery/data-recovery
sudo chroot /recovery
su - user

ecryptfs-mount-private
cd /home/username

sudo mount -o bind /home/username /data-recovery
```

Remember, don't close the terminal until you are done with the data if you bind it.  Once you bind it you should be able to access the folder `/data-recovery` (from the LiveCD root) and pull all the data using a GUI.  If the last bind does not work, you can remove the last bind and simply cp -avr everything from `/home/username` to the chroot `/data-recovery` and it show up in the liveCD `/data-recovery`.