# Where is my encrypted home folder?

Tags: 11.04, ecryptfs

I'm following [these instructions for 11.04](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html) to decrypt my /home/torben folder of my old drive so that I can copy it onto my new drive. It seems to succeed:

> INFO: Success!  Private data mounted read-only at [/tmp/ecryptfs.xtltX0TT/private].

but I can't find the decrypted files in the /tmp/... location given in the command's output. **Where are the files?**

Comment: What is the output of `cd /tmp/ && ls`? What is inside /tmp/ when you open it with nautilus `nautilus /tmp/`?

Comment: Based on the [help from Marco Ceppi in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1874601#1874601), and using [these updated instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13177/how-do-i-recover-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory/13178#13178) instead, it now works!

Comment: Glad it worked ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the new decrypt tool for 11.04 didn't work correctly on my system. With Marco Ceppi's help in the chat room, we walked through the manual steps instead, and that worked.

The steps have been updated and can be found in this answer:
[How do I recover data from an encrypted Home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13177/how-do-i-recover-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory/13178#13178)