# Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed

Tags: 11.04, ecryptfs

After entering the correct passphrase at the command `ecryptfs-mount-private`, I am getting this error:

```
torben@torben-nettop:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/media/0f417b42-11a0-4539-9cae-e11ce3b289c3/home/.ecryptfs/
  torben/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring
  failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
torben@torben-nettop:~$
```

Syslog has this information:

```
ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring:  
  Incorrect wrapping key for file [/home/torben/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]  
ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Error attempting to unwrap
  passphrase from file [/home/torben/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]; rc = [-5]
```

**--> Given that I am absolutely sure that I am entering the correct passphrase, what can I do to fix this problem so that I can read the encrypted home folder?**

Some background:

- I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on a new drive and I want to copy my home folder from the old drive, which is encrypted (I have the passphrase).
- With the help of [Marco Ceppi in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1874601#1874601), I followed [these precise steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13177/how-do-i-recover-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory/13178#13178) yesterday and successfully gained access to the encrypted home folder. This proves that my passphrase does indeed work.
- I then started the machine on copying from the old encrypted home folder to the new unencrypted home folder and went to bed. When I returned to the computer, I saw that it had suspended itself :( and had not finished copying the folder.
- I rebooted the computer, and removed the temporary */recovery* folders, then followed the exact same steps again, but this is when I encountered the error given above. I tried this several times; always the same result. I am absolutely sure that I am typing the passphrase correct.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this area - hence the comment not an answer - have you tried the steps by "1awsomeguy" in this linked post?  http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1471961.html

Comment: That forum post refers to instructions that are no longer valid. The instruction webpage clearly states to [use a newer tool instead](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html), which is what I tried to use in the question above. The only difference is that I'm not booting off a USB "LiveCD" but running it locally, because the encrypted folder in question is not local but on an external disk.

Comment: Possibly a fast way - have you tried contacting the ecryptfs developer directly? Here are his contacts: http://launchpad.net/~kirkland   He seems friendly. Sending him the link to this question may get him curious as it is very specific and still unanswered.

Comment: @strapa - good idea! I did send a question on Launchpad but omitted this webpage. That might work!

Comment: Apparently nobody knows what this error message means ... what a fruitless waste of my rep! :'-(

Comment: As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285541/mount-no-such-file-or-directory-with-encrypted-recovery/395391#comment878481_395391, it's helpful to run `sudo ecryptfs-manager`, then press 4 (exit), then run `ecryptfs-recover-private` again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated**: *19 June 2018*

### Summary

I was recently getting the a similar error, when trying to decrypt some data from an external drive.  Every time the error message was from an invalid password, I can duplicate this all day long.  Instead using **ecryptfs-recover-private** I was using **ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase**, which I think is for specific data, though I don't feel like looking up the difference.

**Note:** This is not a copy/paste guide, it is more of a record of my success.

### Unwrapping The Passphrase

You'll need to find your `wrapped-passphrase` file. If you're not sure where it is you can use `find`.  After you mount your volume you can do:

```
sudo find /media -name wrapped-passphrase
```

You'll want to substitute the path which returns for my paths listed below.

My steps after mounting the old drive.

```
cd /media/_UUID_/.ecryptfs/paulj/.encryptfs
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ./wrapped-passphrase
Passphrase:
```

It will always prompt for a passphrase, this is the password initially setup when you created the encrypted home directory when you installed Ubuntu.  In the setup it highly recommends that you use a different password than your login password... if you've been trying your login password for the last hour and failing, try some different ones .. try that one password which you rarely use.

I had forgotten what mine was, I tried all of my super awesome passwords, and I kept getting this error message:

```
Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
```

After searching google for about an hour, I figured I'd try a password I knew was bad, so I put in **password** at the Passphrase prompt.

The following was spit out:

```
116b053e08564b53b2967e64e509bdc5
```

I reran ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase and tried a different password and received the same -5 error message as listed above.  It turns out that I had actually set the passphrase to **password**, probably due to my frustrations with decrypting data in ubuntu in the past.

### Add Passphrase to Keying

Adding the passphrase to `ecryptfs-add-passphrase`, use the passphrase generated in the previous step.

```
sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
Passphrase: 116b053e08564b53b2967e64e509bdc5
```

Outputs:

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [b69fed2a22932ba4] into the user session keyring
Inserted auth tok with sig [8aad0fb4482edab3] into the user session keyring
```

### Mount or Recover

At this point you have two options, I suggest attempting to mount, then if you can't mount, try recovering.

#### Mounting the Drive

It is easy to think of the `.Private` directory as an unmounted volume.

Again here you'll need to specify your own directories.

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/paulj/Private
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /media/_UUID_/.ecryptfs/paulj/.Private /home/paulj/Private

Passphrase: 116b053e08564b53b2967e64e509bdc5
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (loaded)
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56 (not loaded)
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24 (not loaded)
 4) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (not loaded)
 5) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16 (not loaded)
Selection [aes]: aes

Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 16

Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: n

Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y <-- If your filenames display oddly, toggle this to y or n.

{this is the second value from Inserted auth tok...}
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature: 8aad0fb4482edab3

Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=8aad0fb4482edab3
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=b69fed2a22932ba4
Mounted eCryptfs
```

Hopefully when you initially created the encrypted drive you didn't mess around with the cypher or key bytes.

Shows all data in my old home directory.

```
cd /home/paulj/Private
ls -la
```

**Note:** At this point if you get invalid permission/owner/group sets, you're going to want to unmount the drive and skip down to the Recover section.

If you get a good permission set, copy that junk out out of the encrypted drive to the desktop for example.

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/Backup
cp -Rv ./* ~/Desktop/Backup
```

#### Recover

I discovered I couldn't successfully mount my ecryptfs. `ls` was displaying invalid permission/owner/group settings.  It looked something like the following:

```
total ??
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .
d????-??-?   6 root    root    4.0K Jun 19 11:42  ..
d???------  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .aptitude
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .autoenv
-??-?--?--  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .autoenv_authorized
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .aws
-??-?--?--  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .bash_aliases
-??-------  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .bash_history
-??-?--?--  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .bash_logout
-??-?--?--  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .bashrc
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            bin
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .cache
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            code
d????-??-?  ?? ??      ??      ??   ??            .config
```

I am not sure why I wound up with problems with using `mount`, so I started messing around with `ecryptfs-recover-private` and had some luck.

Again, you'll have to use your own generated passphrase from above.  Note that I used the `--rw` switch here to make the mount read/write, if you omit the switch it will mount read-only.

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private --rw /media/_UUID_/.ecryptfs/paulj/.Private

INFO: Found [/media/_UUID_/.ecryptfs/paulj/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 116b053e08564b53b2967e64e509bdc5
Inserted auth tok with sig [b69fed2a22932ba4] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.idv9OohY].
```

The `tmp` path it outputs will contain your encrypted mount.

```
ls -la /tmp/ecryptfs.idv9OohY
```

This should show your full path with proper permission sets. Now copy it out somewhere.

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/Recovered
sudo cp -Rv /tmp/ecryptfs.idv9OohY ~/Desktop/Recovered
```

### In Closing

**GOOD LUCK!!**

You should be able to use this for any variant of Ubuntu, I for instance have used it in and between Ubuntu and Mint and Lubuntu.

If you're just finding this thread, unless you specifically used **password** as your Passphrase, those hex values won't work.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it _appears_ to contain the exact solution. My password wasn't actually _"password"_ so my keys would be different. Alas, the drive has since been formatted because I gave up looking for a solution, so it's not of much relevance to me any more. And I've learned to not encrypt my home drive for no reason :-)

Comment: Pretty much the exact lesson I learned.  I figured I'd post my experience to help any other person who stumbled on this thread.

Comment: @paulj You've earned the Ass Savior badge.

Comment: @robertodecurnex -- Happy to help, I've completely given up on Ubuntu, due to it constantly screwing me in some way. I stick to Mint Desktop and sometimes CENTOS server.

Comment: I run into the same situation and I was able to mount it after adding the passphrase, but now I can see ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED... files only. Is there any way to get not encrypted files?

Comment: @RomanNewaza honestly I have no idea, sorry :(  I haven't used Ubuntu since I made this post.  I recommend making a new topic to see if anyone can help you out.  Good luck buddy!

Comment: @paulj Thank you! This steps worked precisely for me, even though my situation was different (I think). I had an encrypted `/home` in a Linux Mint and used a Debian live usb stick to do as you suggested. I had already found similar answers elsewhere, but I always ended up with a strange error at the end. The one different thing that you do is `sudo mkdir -p /home/paulj/Private`. Now I know the error was related to permissions somehow.

Comment: @marcelocra yeah it was really just written as a historical log of what I did, more than a copy/paste thing.  I recall having lots of weird problems using others' guides.

Comment: Updated: 19 June 2018.

Answer (score 4):

*This is an attempt to fix it myself:*

1. Dustin Kirkland [wrote in 2008](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/283477#11):

   > [...] you're trying to unwrap the mount passphrase with the wrong login password. You might try both your current, and your new password, or any other that you might have used. 
   >   When you can unwrap your mount passphrase successfully, you should be able to perform the mount.
2. The login username and login password for the new system are identical to the ones for the old system. I *have* written down the passphrase and I know it's correct (see proof in my question).
3. This similar problem might be worth checking out: [Trying to mount old encrypted home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home/36783#36783)
4. Also, something on the new system might not be working correctly. To rule this out, boot on a LiveCD and try from there.

***...to be updated as I go along!***

Answer (score 0):

In case the password does not work ( which happened to me, though I had not changed it ), using the backup passphrase to access helped me. I just answered no to whether I knew my password and entered the 32 long hex number I had received and written down upon initial boot.

This may be easier at times than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be of any help, while I was facing a similar issue (code `-5` during decryption of home directory), I found out some files under `.ecryptfs` and `.Private` were not owned by my user account but rather by root.

This happened because I ran `ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase` as root and as such it locked important files away from my own account.

Hence, when I ran `ecryptfs-mount-private` with my user account, it would fail as reading and writing to some files (namely `.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`) was be denied.

I solved my case by running `sudo chown -R USER:USER /home/USER/.ecryptfs /home/USER/.Private`. Replace `USER` by your actual account name. YMMV