# ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase FAILS with WORKING loggin password?

Tags: login, password, ecryptfs

```
sudo ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/username/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

This should work with my 'login' password.
I'm **logged in** to the user account, I can see my files, yet that command fails with

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
Passphrase: 
Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
```

Of course syslog is silent

I've changed my pass few weeks ago, all works at the moment, except that command - so I'm a bit surprised, how can I unwrap the key?

Is that some version incompatibility?

Comment: Why on earth do you write in all caps???

Comment: I guess I'm frustrated how stupid the logic of ecryptfs is, are you annoyed by that?

Comment: @CharlesGreen you have marked this question as a possible duplicate.
Can you quote a section of that "duplicated" thread where they suggest to try this simple trick as 'fill in the initial (old) installation password'?

How on earth this is a duplicate? Did you even read it?

Im not in the mood today, after fighting this case, and I wish I'd find this solution earlier. That is why I invest my time to make it public.

By people like you it may not be visible to others who would have such issue in the future.

Please explain your motivation to mark it as a duplicate. Please...

Comment: @sirkubax I'm sorry about that!  I had seen both this and the answer you attempted to post at [https://askubuntu.com/a/1134458/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134458/283721), and did not look too closely after that.

Comment: No problem, thanks for clarification :) Have a nice day!

Comment: dmesg and the syslog had nothing new? Verified the syslog is working with something like `logger test`?

Comment: Also, your answer to use an old password is exactly what a developer said, [in this answer from the potential duplicate Q](https://askubuntu.com/a/62257/129271) - sounds like that other Q really is a duplicate, same problem and same answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, what the HACK
It works with my OLD (very first initial) password.

This is so stupid - if you are a developer - please explain to me, why at the login it works with my **current** password to decrypt and mount the files,
yet to wrapped-password (and I guess also to re-wrap it) it I need paste my old (very very old, maybe compromised?) password?

some other topic
https://askubuntu.com/a/107660/579000